# Empty value in application.properties leads to "Could not resolve placeholder" exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, server

We got a spring-boot application which reads it's configuration from a configuration-server.

I encountered a problem reading empty properties using the spring-cloud-configuration-server.

Setting is a KV-pair with no value in application.properties.
e.g. 
MyKey=

Loading it "regular" using just a file no problem is raised.

But when the client uses a configuration-server, the empty value is leading to a:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MyKey'".

Looks for me there is something weird in the config-server.
So here is the application.yml of it:

```
info:
  version: '@project.version@'
  artifact: '@project.artifactId@'
server:
  port: 10805
spring:
  application:
    name: ${info.artifact}
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
  boot:
    admin:
      discovery:
        enabled:  true
      context-path: /admin
  jmx:
    enabled: false
endpoints:
  jmx:
    enabled: false
turbine:
  combineHostPort: true
  app-config: service.us
  clusterNameExpression: "'default'"

---
spring:
  profiles: win
eureka:
  server:
    disable-delta: true
    disable-delta-for-remote-regions: true
  instance:
    hostname: ${COMPUTERNAME}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:10805/eureka/
archaius:
  deployment:
    datacenter: ${eureka.instance.hostname}
    environment: local

---
spring:
  profiles: default
eureka:
  instance:
    virtual-host-name: ${eureka.instance.appname}
    app-group-name: ces
    appname: admin.ces

---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: subversion
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        svn:
          uri : https://myserver/svn/ces/trunk/config/
          username: conf
          password: ****
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

The configuration-server drives an eureka-server aswell.
This combination leads to the behavior described above.

Removing the annotation AND the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

solves the problem.

So our idea to run both services on the same instance is currently not realisable.

Used versions:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RS4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```